# Plot a bar plot using department wise toppers using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Department wise toppers (horizantal bar graph or any visual representations of your choice)

I need to plot a bar graph using department wise toppers from the below table

[Data set Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUoH5.png)

```
index   Name    python  mysql   Previous Geekions   CodeKata Score  Average Score   Department  Rising  python_en   computational_thinking
0   A.Dharani   82.0    20.0    24500   24500   24500.0 Computer Science and Engineering    0   NaN NaN
1   V.JEEVITHA  82.0    20.0    21740   21740   21740.0 Computer Science and Engineering    0   NaN NaN
2   HEMAVATHI.R 100.0   100.0   19680   19680   19680.0 Computer Science and Engineering    0   NaN NaN
3   Mugunthan S 100.0   47.0    10610   10610   10610.0 Computer Science and Engineering    0   NaN NaN
```

I have tried the below code, but I am not able to get the name of the toppers.

```py
DToppers=df.groupby('Department')['CodeKata Score'].max()
DToppers.plot(kind='bar', title='Department wise toppers')

fig.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do not post images. It is otherwise hard to help you. Post a sample of the dataframe. Do this by print(df) and then post the result in the post (between ```  and ```)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some example data, I only included the relevant columns and split the 4 records into 2 different departments to show the behaviour:

```
data = {
    'Name': ['A. Dharani', 'V.JEEVITHA', 'HEMAVATHI.R', 'Mugunthan S'],
    'CodeKata Score': [24500, 21740, 19680, 10610],
    'Department': ['Department1', 'Department1', 'Department2', 'Department2']
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now get a DataFrame where the row matches the calculated max:

```
DToppers = df.loc[df.groupby(['Department'])['CodeKata
Score'].idxmax()]
```

Now plot which is very similar to your original - Not sure if you wanted the names and departments on the plot - you will need to adjust the x values and/or set the labels if you do.

```
DToppers.plot(x='Name', y='CodeKata Score', kind='bar', title='Department wise toppers')
```

NB: Think about what you want to happen if more than one person has the same "high score" in the department. Of course if you are only wanting to show department names that won't matter, but does give you a problem/decision if you want the names on there.